# Is it possible to add some parameters to the create authorization resource?

Tags: laravel

I have this policy: (extract of GroupPolicy.php)

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return (
        $user->role_id === 'SUPERADMIN'
        ||
        $user->role_id === 'ADMIN'
    );
}
```

I would like to add some other conditions in this policy by injecting another object coming from my controller. If I have understood, this method 'create' accepts only the connected user.

Is it possible, and how, to add other parameters for this policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as many arguments as you want to the policy method, they have to be in an array though:

Your Controller:

```php
public function create()
{
    $var1 = new \stdClass();
    $var2 = 123;
    $this->authorize('create', [User::class, $var1, $var2]);
}
```

Your Policy:

```php
public function create(User $user, $var1, $var2)
{
    return (
        $user->role_id === 'SUPERADMIN'
        ||
        $user->role_id === 'ADMIN'
    );
}
```